# sql server insert missing ID values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has four column

```
ID, day, Shift 1 and shift 2
```

id is 30,32

day is today and yesterday and

shift 1 and shift 2 has some values for today entry

there is no data for id 32

I want that if data is not there for a particular id then it should show "-"

current output is

```
ID, day,     shift1,    shift2 
30, today,   4,        4
30,  yesterday,    5,         6
32,  yesterday,     9,         8
```

but I want output as

```
ID, day,      shift1,    shift2, 
30,  today,    4,         4
32,  today,    -,        -
30,  yesterday,     5,         6
32,  yesterday,     9,         8
```

Like if data is not there for any of the ids for each day then it should show as - in the shift

Kindly suggest something to me. thank you

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I changed the tag to "sql-server" (from "mysql") based on the title.

Comment: thanks, Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, day, ifnull(shift1,'-') as shift1, ifnull(shift2,'-') as shift2
from tablename
```

your tag is mysql so the answer firstly for mysql

however your heading is sql server so below the answer for sql server:

```
select id, day, isnull(shift1,'-') as shift1, isnull(shift2,'-') as shift2
from tablename
```

you obviously need to replace tablename with the actual name of your table

Answer (score 1):

If the shift columns are strings, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select id, day, coalesce(shift1, '-') as shift1, coalesce(shift2, '-') as shift2
from tablename;
```

However, this won't work if the columns are numbers.  In that case, you need to convert the values to strings first:

```
select id, day,
       coalesce(cast(shift1 as varchar(255)), '-') as shift1,
       coalesce(cast(shift2 as varchar(255)), '-') as shift2
from tablename;
```

The syntax is slightly different in MySQL:

```
select id, day,
       coalesce(cast(shift1 as char), '-') as shift1,
       coalesce(cast(shift2 as char), '-') as shift2
from tablename;
```